# Why are my has_many :through associations not working correctly on delete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My has_many :through associations on Releases/Products/Tracks seem to be deleting the the Track and leaving orphaned associations in the releases_tracks / products_tracks tables. I can't see where i've gone wrong, I thought the default behavior is to delete the association only. Can anyone help please?

My Models:

```
 class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :releases_tracks
   has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks

   has_many :products_tracks
   has_many :products, :through => :products_tracks 
 end

 class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :releases_tracks
   has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks
 end

 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products_tracks
   has_many :tracks, :through => :products_tracks
   before_save do
     self.track_ids = self.releases_track_ids
   end
 end

 class ProductsTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :track
 end

 class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :release
   belongs_to :track
 end
```

My Track Controller (for the destroy action):

```
 class TracksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_track_parent

 def destroy
   @track = @parent.tracks.find(params[:id])
   @track.destroy
   redirect_to @parent  
 end

 private

 def get_track_parent
   if params[:product_id].present?
   @parent = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   elsif params[:release_id].present?
   @parent = Release.find(params[:release_id])
   end
 end
 end
```

My destroy link in the releases view:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("icons/delete.png"), release_track_path(@release,track), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

And finally, my destroy link in the products view:

```
 <%= link_to image_tag("icons/delete.png"), product_track_path(@product,track), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Comment: You might need `:dependent => :destroy` on the association
Ex: `has_many :products, :through => :products_tracks, :dependent => :destroy`

Comment: Afraid that doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need `:dependent => :destroy` option for your associations:

```
class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :releases, :through => :releases_tracks # also note you had here :tracks instead of :releases

  has_many :products_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :products_tracks 
end
```

And also if you want tracks to be removed when removing releases or products, add following `:dependent => :destroy`s:

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :products_tracks
  before_save do
    self.track_ids = self.releases_track_ids
  end
end

class ProductsTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :track, :dependent => :destroy
end

class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Comment: Thanks, finally moving forward with this now! I've added :dependent => :destroy as pointed out on my Tracks model and now the association is being deleted along with the track, however, I want to delete the associations only and leave the track in the database.

Comment: Still unable to delete just the associations here, can anyone offers some guidance?

Comment: Could you please explain your problem more clearly? Can you provide code of what you are trying to do?